# Remove dependency from nested Lerna Package

Tags: package.json, lerna

I have a lerna setup with `n` packages located under `packages/`.  Let us take an example where one of the packages uses express where the others do not.

How can I remove express from this package in a lerna-aware manner so the root package.json is updated?

I can add packages with `lerna add --scope` but it seems there is no corresponding remove functionality.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just remove the packages from your package.json

then run

`$lerna bootstrap`

Comment: This does not remove entries from `package-lock.json` unfortunately

Answer (score 18):

1. Remove package from `package.json`
2. Remove node_modules folder: `rm -rf packages/{package_name}/node_modules`
3. Run `lerna bootstrap`

Without step 2 the package still exists in the `package-lock.json` NPM lock file.

Comment: This generated the package-lock.json updates that I wanted. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be sure that `lerna bootstrap` **only** updates the **specific** `package-lock.json` in `@org-name/package-name/` and not other `package-lock.json` files, do:

1. Manually remove dependencies from `@org-name/package-name/package.json`
2. Remove the whole `node_modules` directory for this one package

```bash
rm -rf packages/package-name/node_modules
```

3. Now bootstrap only this one package.

```bash
lerna bootstrap --scope @org-name/package-name --no-ci --force-local
```